# Auto-Selecting Navigation on a one page site

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a one page website and I want my menu items to highlight when the user either scrolls or clicks from one menu item to the other.

The way I'm currently trying is:

```
   <nav>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#what">What I Do</a></li>
           <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
           <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
```

I'm trying this jQuery but it doesn't seem to activate the `.selected` in the css?

```
 $(function(){
       var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
       if ( path )
             $('nav a[href$="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
  });
```

css

```
.selected {
   color: #f9b950;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`location.pathname` does not include the hash. You have to use `location.hash` instead.
Also, don't forget to remove the `selected` class from the previous element.

The `[href="value"]` selector will select the exact attribute value of an element. It does not select resolved URIs. That's why you can use `a[href="#hashhere"]` instead of `a[href$="#hashere"]`.

The `hashchange` event can be used to detect changes in `#`.

```
function doSomethingWithHash() {
   var path = location.hash;
   var as = $('nav a[href="' + path + '"]');
   if (as.length) {
       $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
       as.attr('class', 'selected'); // not .addClass('selected'); //?
   }
}
$(doSomethingWithHash); // = document.ready
$(window).bind('hashchange', doSomethingWithHash); // When navigating
```

This does not cause a problem, but you have to consider it:

- `.attr('class', 'selected')` removes all of the previous classes, and sets `class` to `selected`.
- `.addClass('selected')` adds `selected` to the set of classnames (if it didn't exist yet). Previous classes will not be removed.

Comment: Thanks Rob and xdazz but I'm still not having much luck with it. I tried the above in Firefox nothing seemed to change but in Safari if I reloded the page the change would take effect here's what all the code for my page looks like http://pastebin.com/9wMisKDL

Comment: @Nsokyi I have edited my answer to include a detection for hash changes. I did not implement your scroll request, because that would potentially affect the user experience in a bad way, especially with multiple anchors. You would have to bind a `scroll` event to `window`, and check for each element whether the element is within the viewport, using [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

Comment: oh I see, sort of... This is the user interface I'm kinda going for do you think these guys are doing it wrong too? http://kiskolabs.com/#home (I'm not trying to be confrontational I'm just interested to see what you think) Thanks

Comment: @Nsokyi The code (jQuery plugin and implementation) be found here: http://kiskolabs.com/javascripts/frontpage.js (`$("#wrapper > section").waypoint({ offset: viewportTop });`, at the top of the code) and http://kiskolabs.com/javascripts/waypoints.js (the plugin itself).

Answer (score 0):

For the click event on li.

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu li').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks xdazz that works for the click side of things, just need to figure out the scrolling part.